# EB GUIDE Studio extension doesn't work anymore after switching to version 6.8

Tags: c#, plugins

I tried to migrate an extension from Guide 6.7.3 to 6.8. Compilation did work without any changes, but the DLL is not loaded anymore.

It looks like the DLL is not even loaded, breakpoint in main constructor is not hit and Visual Studio claims that there are no symbols available.
Same version works correctly in Guide 6.7.3.

Stripped down minimal version which shows the problem:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.Xml;

    using Elektrobit.Guide.Studio.Workbench.ViewModels;
    using Elektrobit.Guide.Ui.ViewModels;
    using Elektrobit.Guide.Utilities;

    [Export(typeof(IMenuItemProvider))]
    public class TestMenuProvider : IMenuItemProvider
    {
        public string MenuId => "test";

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public TestMenuProvider()
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable<IMenuItemViewModel> CreateMenuItems(object context)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Constructor TestMenuProvider() is run on 6.7.3 but not 6.8.

Comment: Have you reached out to the vendor: https://www.elektrobit.com/ebguide/contact-us/  seems like the logical first step.

Comment: Actually I tried to get into direct contact with the community of Guide users instead of going the official way, which is likely to take longer. I was also hoping to make the fix for this issue public so that other users can benefit as well (instead of hiding it in an email conversation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code works fine for me.

However, I stumpled upon a similar issue, so this might help you:

As they switched from x86 to x64 with version 6.8, I could imagine you may have missed to update the build settings of your extension project.

In the project properties of the Visual Studio project, head for `Build -> Platform target` and make sure it is set to x64 for all build configurations.